# How can I locate additional GCPs?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I'm a new user of QGIS. I'm georeferencing a scanned image of topographic map. At least 16 GCPs were required for us to locate. However, only 12 can be located and can be identified and be defined based from the coordinates given in the corners, horizontal and vertical borders and tick marks in the middle.

Are there any other ways to obtain define coordinates of other GCPs accurately? Is interpolation possible in this case? If yes, how?

Comment: Why do you need so many GCPs? Is the scan badly distorted?

Comment: @nhopton No, but we were required to locate at least 16 GCPs

Comment: @Nomad Why is it required?

Comment: Sounds like homework? ;)

Comment: Okay, it's an exercise. You could have a look at the area in Google Earth and see if it's possible to match four features on the imagery with four features on your map and note the GE coordinates for them. Obviously I don't know what CRS you are using but you can set GE to show UTM coordinates if required.

Answer (score 2):

I usually find that there are readily identifiable features that can be matched to other available GIS data.  Obviously you must be content with the accuracy of the data you are matching your image to and the accuracy with which you can locate the feature (and a lot will depend on the resolution of the image).  If the level of accuracy is critical (which the requirement of 16 points suggests it is), then purchasing a small area of high quality data may be worthwhile rather than using freely available data.

Twelve GCPs based on tick marks and border info is a luxury I don't think I have ever had for a single image!  Therefore, since you have so many great GCPs you have a great sanity check for your additional points (cross-referenced features to other GIS data) by checking the change in the RMS error before and after you add your four final points.